# Linking share point default attachment path to document library

Tags: list, document-library, custom-list, document, list-form

I am new to SharePoint and I want to understand if it is possible to send the document that is attached to a list from its default "Attachments" folder to a custom document library. I want to do this so that I can maintain versions of the document uploaded into the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List attachments are not stored in a library. Lists and libraries handle files in different ways. If you want versioning, then you need to store the files in a library. You may need to change your data architecture to have the file uploaded to a library and then create a list item in a separate list that contains a link to the file in the library. Such a scenario can be handled with workflows.

**Edit:** If you are new to SharePoint, you may want to learn about using SharePoint Designer and creating workflows.

Then create the list with the fields that hold the data about the document.

In the document library, create a workflow that gets triggered when a new document is created. Let that workflow create a new item in the list and populate the fields in that list item with the metadata from the current library item.

This can include a document ID (if you have that service enabled) and/or a link to the document if you use a HTML field in the list and in the workflow construct the URL with the current file name.

I don't know about a tutorial for exactly this scenario, but the internet has lots of materials about SharePoint workflows. Just break it down into small pieces and take it one thing at a time.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn. I appreciate it. Can you direct me towards a direction where I can go and learn how to do this, preferably with an example.

Comment: I added a few ideas to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. To maintain the version of a document you should upload to the document library and enable the versioning feature. If you have additional metadata to the document you can create metadata fields.

You can read [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to understand versioning

You can read [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-column-in-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2) to manage the metadata columns for a list or library.

Instead of using a SharePoint list you should use the document library which helps to store documents and maintain metadata.